# Measuring salient changes in 2 Dimensional clusters using using existing functions in Matlab

Tags: distributions, clustering, data-visualization, distance, distance-functions

I have a series of frames where I want to analyse changes in spatial distributions of points. I have a list of x,y values or 2D coordinates measuring changes in particle distribution.

As shown in the image with red arrows and black arrows the changes are not big, they are in the order of no more 15% displacements, particles also come and go.

I need help to:

1. Suggest a means of capturing these changes in a quantitative way.
2. Preferably an existing routine in Matlab which I can quickly deploy in a batch mode.
3. A measure which also quickly show this at a glance with a plot of how this spatial distribution or cluster changes over frames.

If you could also point me to a paper that does this in a clean, rigorous and straight forward way, that would be really nice[image].

I thank you for your kind help.

Cheers

Rigu

Comment: Are the points labeled with an ID (analogous to 'patient 7'), such that you know a given point in one frame is the same as the point in another?

Comment: Though the frames are labelled.